# Can I make a content type for a single user's blog entries?

Tags: nodes

I would like site announcements to appear in a block on the sidebar.

I can do that with a content type, but Admin has a blog and I was wondering if/how to automatically give all blog posts of Admin (and no other user) be of a content type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is to create a view. Show all blog entries by 'user 1' only in your block. 
Create a view: Under your display(on the left) select block from the drop down. Give it 
a name, say Test1.
Under Fields add Node:Title and Node:Body.
In the filters add Node-type:Blog, Node:Published:Yes and User:Name=Admin

Then goto Site building->Blocks and you should see Test1:Viewname. Enable that block and configure it to show it on the page where you'd like.

Hope that helps.

Comment: +1 but, alas, not the answer yet. As you can tell, I am a n00b. I have just been reading about views in my Drupal book and should have known that. Thanks for reminding me.  Unfortunately ...

Comment: When I try to create such a view I get a message about invalid SQL - which I would never expect to happen as Drupal is generating the SQL for me??!!   If I try to create a view with User Id = 1 then I get SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= '1') ))) subquery' at line 1

Comment: at the bottom of admin/structure/views/view/site_announcements   same sort of thing if I try author=Admin   Should I be reporting this is a bug?  Maybe in the Views module?

Comment: Hi, I don't think its a bug :) Could you post the steps you did.. I'm updating my answer to be more specific

Comment: There was an update to the views module this morning and suddenly it works. Thanks for all of your help